# Css Flex display as row with two item display as column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to make a flex element with item display as row but 2 items display as column?

[image]

I want to display like this

[image]

```css
    .nav{
        height: 44px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .item{
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 60px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .item.inline{
        background: lightcoral;
        height: 20px;
    }
```

```html
**HTML:**

    <div class="nav">
      <a href="#" class="item">1</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">2</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">3</a>
      <a href="#" class="item inline">4</a>
      <a href="#" class="item inline">5</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">6</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you want this to be dynamically (adjust with each items content), you need either to wrap item 4 and 5, use script or CSS Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapped column which looks like a row:

```css
.nav, .item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 44px;
}

.item {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item.inline {
  background: lightcoral;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#" class="item">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">3</a>
  <a href="#" class="item inline">4</a>
  <a href="#" class="item inline">5</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">6</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @DuyHung, happy to help!